# What is the difference between abstract and comment in DBpedia

Tags: dbpedia

What is the difference between abstract and comment for any DBpedia resources?
is it some one is short description than the other one?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question. The [DBpedia website](http://dbpedia.org/) includes a wealth of information about the DBpedia project, and the [DBpedia discussion mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion) is a good place to ask about missing points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBpedia abstracts usually* include the first paragraph of a Wikipedia page as simple text. Comments are substrings of abstracts limited to two sentences.

(*) "usually" because sometimes text extraction fails, and no abstract is produced.

(disclaimer: I am a DBpedia developer)